# CORS Error with react-native and expo-web

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo to build my mobile application. But I want to test also on expo-web. When I try to make a request to my backend on expo-web, I'm getting CORS Error on patch and put requests. There is no problem on virtual device or real device. I also test my backend on postman. Everything is OK.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.mvcMatcher("/api/**")
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration()
                .applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/api/non-secured/patients/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();}
```

Here is my Security Configurer.

```
export async function putFetch(url: string, body: any) {
const token = getAuthToken();
const requestOptions = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
};
const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
if (response.status === 400) {
    throw new Error("Bad Request");
}
if (response.status === 401) {
    throw new Error("Unauthorized");
}
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`);
}
return await response.json();}
```

```
export async function patchFetch(url: string, body?: any) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await getAuthToken()}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };
  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  if (response.status === 400) {
    throw new Error("Bad Request");
  }
  if (response.status === 401) {
    throw new Error("Unauthorized");
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`);
  }
  return await response.json();
}
```

here is my request parts.

Could you help me to find why I'm getting CORS Error on Expo-web

Comment: Try add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")` in your controller class

Comment: @wnotunas . are you sure it is a good way to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

you can add The allowed origins along with allowed methods globally.

in a configuration class implement WebMvcConfigurer and override "addCorsMappings" method.

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(yourOriginsHere)
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PATCH", "PUT");
}
```